# How do I get my script to pull the date that it is in the sheet, and not auto-correct to the current date?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I am working on creating a communication system where information is inputted multiple times a day via a google form, dumped into a google sheet, that information is compiled into another page within that sheet as part of an overall daily report, and then again transferred to a google doc that gets emailed after a button-click on the original sheet. I want the data that is tied to the date inputted on the sheet to be pulled onto the google doc, because sometimes the email is not triggered until the following day. However what is happening is that if the email is triggered on a different day than the one the data is from, it automatically pulls data from the current date (the date on which the email is being triggered).

Here is the snip of code:

```
  var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "MM-dd-yyyy");
  var date = sheet1.getRange('a2').setValue(formattedDate).setNumberFormat('MM/dd/yyyy')
```

And this further down the code:

```
 body.replaceText("{{Date}}", formattedDate)
```

I tried replacing "formattedDate" above with "date" but that produced an error in that in the spot where the date would be on the google doc, it instead said "Range." I'm not sure what else to try, as I am very new to coding.

So, to sum up, I want the google doc to display whatever date is currently inputted in the google sheet, NOT the current date. Example: Today 3/18 I want to send the report from Friday 3/15.

Comment: First off, I was not the one who downvoted *but* your question can be improved by [editing it](/posts/78168694/edit) and converting it to a [minimal reproducible example (MRE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the problem.  This means stripping out everything irrelevant to the issue in both the problem description as well as the code. This will, at a minimum, make it less work and more appealing for others to engage with your problem, and the process can sometimes provide a solution to a problem in and of itself.

Answer (score 0):

The setNumberFormat method returns a cell range, so if you want to retrieve the date, you also need to add the getDisplayValue method.

from:

```
var date = sheet1.getRange('a2').setValue(formattedDate).setNumberFormat('MM/dd/yyyy')
```

to:

```
var date = sheet1.getRange('a2').setValue(formattedDate).setNumberFormat('MM/dd/yyyy').getDisplayValue();
```

Comment: Thank you for this help! Unfortunately, when I made your suggested adjustment, I am still having the same issue - I put a past date in the google sheet, but when I run the script it automatically changes the date in the sheet to today's date and the form that is triggered also has today's date on it.